# Return single comma from Django template yesno filter

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Is it possible to make the yesno filter return a single comma (",") on true as it is also used as delimiter (`{{foo.bar|yesno:"yup,nope"}}` ~> instead of "yup" return a comma)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as an alternative to the custom filter solution already suggested, you could HTML-encode the comma like so:

```
{{ foo.bar|yesno:"&#44;,nope"|safe }}
```

If you're reusing this logic in many templates then a filter is definitely more maintainable.